# ax 2012 - direct SQL querying alternatives

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am using a direct SQL query as a data source of my SSRS report:

```
SELECT 
    emp.EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
    , amts.AmountCode, amts.amt, amts.AmountType
from EmployeeMaster emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 'Earning' as AmountType, EmployeeNumber, EarningCode as AmountCode
            , SUM(Amount) AS amt 
            FROM EmployeeEarnings GROUP BY EmployeeNumber, EarningCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Deduction', EmployeeID, DeductionID
            , SUM(Amount) AS amt FROM EmployeeDeduction GROUP BY EmployeeID, DeductionId
) AS amts
ON emp.EmployeeNumber = amts.EmployeeNumber
```

This query gathers all the earnings and deductions per employee grouped by employee number, type of earning and type of deduction.  I am unsure of whether I could do this in x++ or an AOT query.  I am wondering if it is alright to do this, or is there be an alternative to produce a result like this query does? I am using RDP class.

Answer (score 3):

Nested joins are not supported in AX.
However you can make a union view of `EmployeeEarnings` and `EmployeeDeduction`.
Then you can select `EmployeeMaster` and outer join with the view to get the same result.

Your SQL is incorrect as it does not consider `dataAreaId` and `Partition`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nested joins are not supported in AX. Yes, you can make a view. And you can use a `ResultSet` class to get result of the `sqlStatement` with a direct-SQL-query via `SQLconnection`.

Some time ago I'd created a wrapper class https://github.com/mazzy-ax/SysResultSet. Comments on Russian only. Sorry. Project to import into ax2012 https://github.com/mazzy-ax/SysResultSet/blob/ax2012/AOT/Classes/Class_SysResultSet.xpo

It simplifies the work with a direct-SQL-query. Try it if you know what you are doing.

And, yes, Your SQL is incorrect as it does not consider `dataAreaId` and `Partition`. In additional your SQL query ignore Axapta XDS (record level security) and Axapta security subsystem. An AOT query is more adequate I think.